# How to get available Hotspot network and show on list in android

Tags: android

I am making a android game in which user can play game using hotspot connectivity like the share it app connect the two user using hotspot.I searched on google but they only show list of wifi network but i only want to show the available hotspot in near by.Please help me guys.I am stuck in this from three days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a BroadcastReceiver to listen for Wifi scan results:

`private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
            // add your logic here
        }
    }
}`

In `onCreate()` you would assign `mWifiManager` and initiate a scan:

```
mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
registerReceiver(mWifiScanReceiver,
new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
mWifiManager.startScan();
```

getScanResults() will return data only if you have appropriate permissions. For this, add one of the following two lines to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Also note that in API 23+, permissions must be requested at runtime. (For a lab environment, you can also grant permissions manually in Settings instead—less coding required, but not recommended for an end-user app.)

Note that the code which handles your scan results would run every time a new scan result is available, updating the result.

Comment: Dharmishtha it shows me wifi list if only my wifi is enabled.but i want to connect using hotspot without the need for wifi like they are doing in share it.